# Electric latch for math toys

Tags: motor, switches, dc

Please fix my tags.

I'm making a series of interactive puzzles for use in classrooms. One of them is an equation graphing. It will have a grid of screws stuck into wood, with the axis drawn on. Students will wrap flexible wire around the screws to complete the circuit. When the circuit is completed the latch should fire allowing a side drawer to be opened. The teacher can configure it with alligator clips inside the box. The other puzzles follow this same concept: buttons, switches, etc complete the circuit allowing power to pass to the latch. That's the general idea, here's the details:

The latch should discontinue the circuit after it opens, so that that current is only ever flowing in that moment. It will run on a few small batteries, so using power continuously to keep it open or closed is undesirable. It's fine if it has to be manually reset, like some kind of electric mouse trap. My question is what would this be called, so I can search for it on amazon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Spring loading...

You could use a spring loaded drawer mechanism. You can then use a solenoid, servo, or other electromechanical device to release the spring and thereby open the drawer. This is similar to how cash register money drawers work.

[image]

[image]

### How it works:

When you push down on the wooden dowel (pin) at the top, it lowers a catch inside that allows the spring behind the drawer to push the drawer out.

[image]

You can make the dowel pressing action electromechanical (EMech) instead of manual by adding a solenoid (there are other ways to do it with other EMech devices).

A solenoid (there are many configurations, the one shown here is the most common) works like this:

[image]

When you apply power a central bar will retract into the solenoid housing. When power is removed a return spring will re-extend the bar. The opposite, latching, and bipolar configurations are also available, so be careful when purchasing.

### Disconnecting power after activation...

To achieve the final part of your spec, disconnecting power after the drawer opens, you will need to add a limit switch behind the drawer that is Normally Open ("N.O."). When the drawer is closed, the switch arm will be pressed back against the switch body, closing the switch.

[image]

When the drawer opens, it will move away from the switch releasing the switch's arm and opening the circuit. This switch must be in series with the solenoid power supply to be effective.

Good luck with your project!

#### Please note:

Project and imagery by Steven Kirk of Cryptic Woodworks (not me).
https://youtu.be/4GHjI6W6s6M

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of circuit you should build. The motor (or solenoid but you need to rearrange the circuit.) is for opening the drawer. And the wires on the bottom of the circuit are the crocodile clips connected to the screws and the flexible conductive wire. The ICs you need 2x 4081, 4078 and 555 timer.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWQJ6.jpg